# How to make CSS3 animation with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I have simple css3 animation:

```
@keyframes vlogo {
    0% {
        transform: rotateX(90deg);
    }
    50%{
        transform: rotateX(200deg)
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotateX(360deg);
    }
}
```

how to run it with jquery animate()?

Comment: You don't. They're two completely separate ways of performing animations.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery `animate` doesn't use CSS animations. If you want to apply a CSS animation using jQuery, you'd need to toggle a class on an element, where the class is defined with the animation.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery animation is totally other thing than CSS animation. All you have to do is add CSS attribute for a element so you should do:

`$(".myelement").css('animation','vlogo 5s');`